# Django rest one-to-many Got AttributeError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Error

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `participant_set` on serializer `MatchSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Match` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'Match' object has no attribute 'participant_set'.

Models.py

```
class TournamentTeam(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(TeamPlayer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Match(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    participant = models.ManyToManyField(TournamentTeam, through='MatchParticipant')

class MatchParticipant(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(TournamentTeam, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    score = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Serializers.py

```
class MatchParticipantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MatchParticipant
        fields = '__all__'


class MatchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    participant_set=MatchParticipantSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = ('name','participant_set')
```

Views.py

```
class MatchAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Match.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MatchSerializer
```

Comment: As the error says, `Match` model doesn't have an attribute `participant_set`. You define the m2m relationship on `Match` to be `participant` so use that. (I'd advise you to call it `participants` since it represents a m2m field).

Comment: But the problem is that `participant` refers to the `TournamentTeam` model. If you want to refer to the through model `MatchParticipant`, then try `matchparticipant_set`.

Comment: it works @dirkgroten thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your model definitions, your `Match` model has the following attributes:

- `participant` is the query manager to query all the `TournamentTeam`s linked to this `Match` (using plural is advised when defining an m2m field, so `participants` would be better). E.g. `match.participant.all()`
- `matchparticipant_set` is the query manager to query the "through" model instances, of type `MatchParticipant`. E.g. `match.matchparticipant_set.all()`.

In the reverse direction, since you haven't defined `related_name` on the `participant` field, you have:

- `TournamentTeam.match_set` for the query manager to fetch the related `Match` instances
- `TournamentTeam.matchparticipant_set` for the `MatchParticipant` instances.